# Overlapping an image on an image... on an image(or in a container)

Tags: html, css

I'm writing a dollhouse app. There is a background area, a doll, and accessories.

The background area should contain the doll (doll position is relative to the background area.)

The doll should contain the accessories (accessory positions will be relative to the bounds of the doll.)

I have no problem getting the background area to contain the doll - Just set the background area to "position:relative", make sure the doll is a descendant and set it to "position:absolute" and it's done.

But the accessory will not behave in the same manner with regard to the doll. I can't set the doll AND the background to position:relative.

The w3schools entry for position:absolute states:

> absolute  The element is positioned relative to its first positioned
>   (not static) ancestor element

Is this definition incorrect? An absolutely positioned child element of an absolutely positioned element does not behave as described. Should this definition say "(only relative)" instead of "(not static)"?

Is there any way to do what I want to do - have an arbitrary (but at least 3) series of elements which are contained and bounded by their parent elements?

Here is code (There is more html but I think this is the entire relevant section. The "hide" class is toggled with JS):

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="display-area">
    <img id="curtains" src ={% static "house/images/curtains.jpg" %} alt="curtains"/>
  {% for doll in doll_objects %}
    <div><img class="hide" src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ doll.doll_image }}" alt="{{ doll.doll_name }}" draggable="false" data-dollid="{{ doll.id }}"/>
      {% for accessory in doll.accessory_set.all %}<div><img class="hide" src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ accessory.accessory_image }}" alt="{{ accessory.accessory_name }}" draggable="false" data-accessoryid="{{ accessory.id }}" data-linkeddoll="{{accessory.doll_id}}" style="position:inherit"/></div>
    {% endfor %}
    </div>
  {% endfor %}
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#display-area {
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    width:78%;
    height:96%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    z-index:0;
}

.doll {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0%;
    left:37%;
    z-index:0;
}

.accessory {
    position:absolute;
    cursor:move;
    cursor:grab;
    z-index:1;
}

.hide {
    visibility: hidden;
}

#container {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100vw;
    height:100vh;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    overflow: auto; /* clearfix */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your accessories div is within your doll div, can you not use position: inherit to give it the same position type as the doll?

Comment: In that case it simply gets bumped out of, and appears right below, the display area (grandparent.)

Comment: would perhaps using z-index not fix the problem by giving the accessories a higher z-index than the doll?

Comment: [link] (https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/z/z-index/) is this the kind of effect you are trying to portray?

Comment: Well, I was already using z-index but it doesn't seem to do anything. I only get one layer of overlapping. And anyway, it's not the overlapping that's the problem, I want the accessory to be positioned relative to the doll so I can easily find an offset and cleanly replicate the relationship between the two objects on other pages.